# Order of rotation

Tags: finite-groups, reflection

For $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^n$, let $s_\alpha$ be the reflection in $\alpha$, i.e. $s_\alpha$ sends $\alpha$ to $-\alpha$ and fixes pointwise the hyperplane orthogonal to $\alpha$. Then if $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}^n$ have an angle of $\theta$ between them, then $s_\alpha s_\beta$ is a rotation by an angle of $2 \theta$. Fine, I get that.

Here's what I don't get. Let $m$ be the order of $s_\alpha s_\beta$, where we see $s_\alpha s_\beta$ as an element of the orthogonal group $O(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and assume $m < \infty$. Then apparently (according to Humpfreys' *Reflection Groups and Coxeter Groups*) the angle between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is $\pi - \dfrac{\pi}{m}$. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a rotation with angle $2θ$ has order $m$, then $2θm=2k\pi$, so that $θ=\frac km \pi$. Now why they choose $k=m-1$ has perhaps reasons that are outside these arithmetic considerations.

---

Let's reduce the situation to the most simple case, $α=e_1$, $β=ce_1+se_2$, $(c,s)=(\cosθ,\sinθ)$ so that the angle from $α$ to $β$ is $θ$ and anything interesting happens in the first two dimensions, with
$$
S_α=\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\quad
S_β=\begin{bmatrix}1-2c^2&-2cs\\-2cs&1-2s^2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then their product is
$$
S_αS_β=\begin{bmatrix}2c^2-1&2cs\\-2cs&1-2s^2\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}\cos2θ&\sin2θ\\-\sin2θ&\cos2θ\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is a rotation by $-2θ$. The smallest rotation in the positive sense can thus be achieved by the angles $-\frac1m\pi$ and $\pi-\frac1m\pi$ from $α$ to $β$.

Comment: But we don't get to chose $k$ ourselves, do we? Isn't it determined by $\theta$ and $m$?

Comment: I do not see why for instance $m=7$ and $k=2$ should not work.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not trying to be obtuse (no pun intended), but are you saying that, given $m$, we can just chose $k$ to be anything we want? That doesn't seem to make sense...

Comment: Yes, if $k$ and $m$ are co-prime, the resulting rotation has order $m$. And note that an angle of $π−\frac πm$ from $α$ to $β$ implies an angle of $\frac πm$ from $β$ to $-α$.